# oracle apex sorting data on chart with Custom sort in underlying query

Tags: oracle-apex-20.1

Oracle apex Charts sort data only in Numeric order even we use Some `sort by` in Underlying Query.
For example I want to Sort data on x axis by Time portion like 7  , 8 am ..... 00 am etc

How i can consider the custom sort so Charts should skip it default sorting functionality

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because Oracle it's treating the data as strings. A-Z or Z-A

What if you try. For example

```
order by to_char(to_date( your_field,'Mon-RR'), 'YYMM')
```

Use the mask that you need obviously.